# Determine Up vector and transform Vector in Matrix.CreateLookAt

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I have

```
Vector3 PlayerPosition = new Vector3(0,0,0);
Matrix JetztMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationX(pitch) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(yaw);
ef.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(PlayerPosition, Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(?1,?2,?3), JetztMatrix) + PlayerPosition, new Vector3(?4,?5,?6));
```

Somehow I always hit some threshold so the screen rolls instead of rotates.

So for instance I give -180° to +180° as yaw. This leads to one turn, but not on a straight "line". As I said, it moves then the screen rolls and it moves again.

How do I determine ?1 to ?6

Comment: In the end, are you just wanting the camera to be oriented the same as jetzMatrix, which has no roll? if so, then Perhaps your question could be: "why when basing my camera on JetzMatrix, which doesn't have any roll in it, does my camera have roll"? the answer would be the 3rd param you are putting into the CreateLookAt(). It should be Vector3.Up instead of whatever you want to get by transforming ?4, ?5, ?6. Then your camera would not roll as it yaws.  But if you aren't trying to orient the camera the same as JetzMatrix, then please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

`ef.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(PlayerPosition, playerPosition + JetzMatrix.Forward, Vector3.Up);`

The `Vector3.Up` will keep the camera from rolling. It's hard to understand exactly what you want to end up with based on your question. If this doesn't solve your issue or creates some other undesirable motion, please describe your desired functionality in more detail.

Comment: "It's hard to understand" No, its easy to understand, provided you have ever put in arbitrary values for ?1 to ?6 and rotated the camera.